# Cannot update the AWS-SDK package in node.js

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-sdk

To this make easier I created a fresh node.js application on VS code. The only package/dependency I install is AWS-SDK. in my package.json the version is shown as `"aws-sdk": "^2.1314.0",`

as far as I am aware the most recent version is 3.270.0. my node.js version is v14.18.1.

I have manually edited pakage.json to reflect the new version then done npm install aws-sdk again, doesnt work. sometimes it reverts back to 2.1314.0, sometimes the version I added remains but npm aws-sdk list command still shows old version

Hope this is enough information! Thanks

Answer (score 0):

First of all stop using version 2 of aws sdk as it is planned to go [into maintenance mode from 2023](https://www.npmjs.com/package/aws-sdk)

Second from version 3, you only use  you  load and use only the individual AWS Services you need to save the the size of code.

> if you need to use only a few AWS services, it means increasing the size of your application with code you don't need or use.

For example to use fynamodb package in version 3 you will use use

```
npm i @aws-sdk/client-s3
```

Coming to your question

- delete node modules directory
- `npm cache clean --force`
- just simple remove the  entry in your package.json and add entry like this

  "dependencies": {

  ```
   "@aws-sdk/client-s3": "^3.256.0"
  ```

  }
- npm i @aws-sdk/client-s3

For reference on aws sdk v3 - https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-javascript/v3/developer-guide/welcome.html